# Bash Script Gammu

Tags: bash

i have script I get an error, Maybe someone knows the problem!

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

rez=$(mysql --user root -pxxxxx xxxxx -Bse "SELECT id,phone,email,date1 FROM xxx WHERE sms='NO'  LIMIT 1;")
echo $rez
array=($(for i in $rez; do echo $i; done))
echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
echo ${array[2]}
echo ${array[3]}
echo ${array[4]}


#echo "Личные даные:"${array[2]}",пароль:"${array[3]}"@015 www.xxxx.ru"  | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "${array[1]}" -unicode

rez2=$(mysql --user root -pxxxxx xxxx_crm -Bse "UPDATE xxx SET sms='YES' WHERE id='${array[0]'")

exit
```

I get the error

```
./send_sms.sh: line 19: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./send_sms.sh: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Which indicates to

```
rez2=$(mysql --user root -paxxxxx xxxx_crm -Bse "UPDATE xxx SET sms='YES' WHERE id='${array[0]'")
```

Comment: Consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking about it here.

Comment: `array=( $rez )` would produce basically the same result as the embedded `for` loop. (There might be slight differences, but neither one is particularly good.)

Answer (score 2):

```
${array[0]
```

is missing a right brace.

```
${array[0]}
```

Comment: (which would make this close-as-typo, no?)

Comment: But if the result is empty I might not go to :#echo "Личные даные:"${array[2]}",пароль:"${array[3]}"@015 www.xxxx.ru"  | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "${array[1]}" -unicode to end?